# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request diagnosing with Fiddler

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest

I am using HttpWebRequest to send a request to a WCF service that uses custom authentication usign the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "User1", "Pwd1");

request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I get a 400 error back.

I checked the request and response headers using Fiddler and here is the request header sent:

```
GET /ProjName/TestService.svc/GetDetails/ABC123 HTTP/1.1

Cookies/Login
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Transport
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: ServerName
```

and I get this as a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 14:21:29 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It may be certificate error or  contract and service implementation mismatch, create console app and debug the call you will get moreinfo

Comment: Console app I already have and it works fine

Comment: please comment input parameters that you have tried in fiddler.

Comment: @DIneshAG, not sure what do you mean?